# json function cannot pass the CKeditor data to backend

Tags: json, ckeditor

I have problem using JSON function to pass data to backend. I cannot json pass the variable `description` value to backend. For example my description values are :

```html
<img alt=&replace_string_val&replace_string_val src=&replace_string_valhttps://www.everyoneknows.com.my/eokclaim/app/uploads/other-brands.jpg&replace_string_val style=&replace_string_valheight:56px; width:100px&replace_string_val /><br />xgds
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Below is sample code:

```html
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
            height: 300,
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
            filebrowserUploadUrl: "/eokclaim/app/ajaxfile.php?type=file",
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "/eokclaim/app/ajaxfile.php?type=image"
} );

<script>
var description = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
</script>
```